# Easiest way to create an equivalent class of this json object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got this json object:

```
{
    foo: {
        someVar: 100,
        anotherVar: "foobar"
    },
    bar: {
        nextVar: "193",
        isThisAVar: true
    },
    foobar: "some text",
    foobool: false,
    barfoo: [
        {
            first: "text",
            second: 391,
            third: "DateTime string"
        },
        {
            first: "text",
            second: 391,
            third: "DateTime string"
        },
        {
            first: "text",
            second: 391,
            third: "DateTime string"
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to create an equivalent class in C# to this json object so I can deserialize the json object with `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>()` (Json.Net).
But I don't want to create a class/structure for `foo`, `bar` and `barfoo`.
I also can't use the dynamic deserialization of Json.Net because my C# class contains some helper function to manipulate the data.

So what is the easiest/fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't want to use classes, nor dynamic serialization... then you need to access the document through token strings (`TryGetValue(...)`) or through indexers (`JObject[...]`), or simply deserialize it to an `object`. _Why_ don't you want to do it the way everyone does it? You also may want to remove the weasel words ("easiest/fastest") and just ask _how_ to do it.

Comment: What's that "C# class" you already have? Do you want to create or modify an existent one?

Comment: by "But I don't want to create a class/structure for..." do you mean you don't want to do it manually?  Or you don't want to have any classes that are representative of the JSON?

Comment: Create anonymous objects?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [http://jsonutils.com](http://jsonutils.com/) to achieve this.

The JSON you entered will be generated to the following class structure:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int someVar { get; set; }
    public string anotherVar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string nextVar { get; set; }
    public bool isThisAVar { get; set; }
}

public class Barfoo
{
    public string first { get; set; }
    public int second { get; set; }
    public string third { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
    public Bar bar { get; set; }
    public string foobar { get; set; }
    public bool foobool { get; set; }
    public IList<Barfoo> barfoo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Web Essentials for Visual Studio will also do this in the editor from the Paste Special menu option.

Comment: _"But I don't want to create a class/structure for foo, bar and barfoo"_

Comment: _"I want to create an equivalent class in C# to this json object so I can deserialize the json object with JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>() (Json.Net)."_

Contradictory? Yes. :-)

Comment: Yeah so that's why I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140521/easiest-way-to-create-an-equivalent-class-of-this-json-object/32140859#comment52170585_32140521) OP to clarify themselves.